# OpenLayers ol-debug.js provisions ol.js property

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm used OpenLayers 4.1.1

I have a function written with ol-debug.js

My goal is to enter the first coordinate manually and simply draw the linestring.

```
ol.interaction.Draw.prototype.startDrawing_ = function (event) {
    var start = event.coordinate;
    this.finishCoordinate_ = start;
    if (1 == 1) {
        this.sketchCoords_ = [start.slice(), start.slice()];
    }
    console.log(this.sketchCoords_);
    var geometry = geometryFunction_(this.sketchCoords_);
    //console.log(geometry);
    this.sketchFeature_ = new ol.Feature();
    this.sketchFeature_.setGeometry(geometry);
    console.log(this.sketchFeature_)
    this.updateSketchFeatures_();
    this.dispatchEvent(new ol.interaction.Draw.Event("drawstart", this.sketchFeature_));
   }
```

My ol-debug.js code works but I need to use ol.js in the project. ol-js is changing the names of these properties due to compression. I want to change these properties in my function, but I haven't found which one corresponds to which one. How do I find the equivalents of ol-debug.js properties for ol.js?

Comment: You could save the ID of compressed one, when you compress it.

Comment: So how do I do this?

Comment: I assume sketchFeature is your compressed one, correct?

Comment: No. I couldn't find the equivalent of finishcoordinate_ ol.js with SketchFeautre_

Comment: So you need to remember both features for later on, to know which start_cord is going with the sketchfeature, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `feature.getId();` to get its id, I forgot if it automaticaly creates it, if it doesnt (returns undefined or null) you could set it. `feature.setId();` if I recall correctly.

You could assign it when you create it aswell. Save it on a global value and then re use it with getFeatureByID (I dont think the function is called exactly like that).

```
var feature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
   id: id
});
```

If you need to reset multiple objects. You could play with layers (Clean all layers and then redraw on it with new elements). *By the way: If I recall correctly, you might be doing it correctly, however you have to redraw layers after you modify some features in it, otherwise it will still remember same geometry.*.

So when you get your ID's you could push it to a global array and then re use it, so you will know which is which.

**Right now I am not sure what your event is on the function (I assume it is your other feature. You could print it out and see if it all ready has an id to use it as well.**

To get element, by specific ID, you should `yourLayer.getFeatureById(featureID).getGeometry().getCoordinates());`

I checked it in my code and seems like I gotten the ID by:

```
var vmarkf = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(coords, null, style);
vmarkf.id;
```

So I assume it is automaticaly generated and you dont really need to set it yourself.

I found the feature with this: `layer.getFeatureById(vmarkf.id));`

Some people say that you need to set ID yourself, in my case it wasn't true, but be aware of that.